# Paging configuration per user

Tags: codeigniter

I use paging in Codeigniter, and I would like to display by default 15 records per page. However, I would like to give the user option to choose how many records per page he would like to see, selecting from the dropdown 30, 50, 100 or all records.

Since I will have this code on more than one place, I would like to avoid repeating same code trough my controllers. Anyone know which is right way how to implement this option according to MVC philosophy? Should this code be placed in some config file?

Answer (score 0):

Either a [library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html), or a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html), would be the best place to have code that is re-used in multiple places

If you want to store the users preference, so your application remembers it, then either store it in the [session](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html), or the [database](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html).

Comment: If I decide to store it in the session, which seems most suitable solution, where that code should goes? Custom config file? Helper?

Comment: A helper file would seem to be most suitable for your needs